# Spawning concurrent tokio tasks that reliably run

Tags: rust, async-await, rust-tokio

I implemented a toy UDP server that simply squirts out data over a set of sockets as fast as it can through several concurrent tasks. I naively thought this would allow efficient use of CPU resources by making use of the Tokio's threaded runtime:

```rust
use std::error::Error;
use std::io;
use tokio::net::UdpSocket;

struct Server {
    socket: UdpSocket,
    buf: Vec<u8>,
    id: u32,
}

const T_LOOPS: usize = 100000;

impl Server {
    async fn run(self) -> Result<(), io::Error> {
        let Server {
            mut socket,
            buf,
            id,
        } = self;

        let peer = "127.0.0.1:9876".to_string();

        loop {
            for _n in 0..T_LOOPS {
                let _amt = socket.send_to(&buf[..], &peer).await?;
            }

            println!("server {} run {} loops", id, T_LOOPS);
        }
    }
}

#[tokio::main(max_threads=8)]
async fn main() -> Result<(), Box<dyn Error>> {
    let addr = "0.0.0.0:0".to_string();

    for n in 0u32..4u32 {
        let socket = UdpSocket::bind(&addr).await?;

        let server = Server {
            socket: socket,
            buf: vec![0; 1500],
            id: n,
        };

        tokio::spawn(async move {
            server.run().await
        });
    }

    Ok(())
}
```

It practice, which tasks run seems to be fairly non deterministic. Generally the first spawned task runs, and any number of the other 3 runs (and not always in order). For example, the output might look something like:

```
server 0 run 100000 loops
server 0 run 100000 loops
server 0 run 100000 loops
```

or

```
server 1 run 100000 loops
server 0 run 100000 loops
server 2 run 100000 loops
server 1 run 100000 loops
server 2 run 100000 loops
server 0 run 100000 loops
```

but is not consistently what I need (which would show all 4 ids).

I can't help but feel I must be missing something here. I've played around with `core-threads` and `max-threads` with no useful result.

How do I make this type of system work reliably with Tokio (or async in general)?

Though this is a toy system, it's actually a stepping stone towards my desired use-case.

Comment: Not sure this is the problem but in your code main ends before spawned futures' execution complete. Please try adding `loop{}` to in your main before `Ok(())`,  to see the results

Comment: @ÖmerErden That absolutely fixes it! I think I was assuming the `tokio::main` was doing more than it was.

Comment: `tokio::main` is basically runs in async context like other futures. In your code there is no future awaits except `UdpSocket::bind`, this is the reason why you see the part of a execution. It will do the job if you await for `tokio::spawn().await?`. But it will just run the first server for your case, because it cannot switch to the others since the future for your first server never ends

Comment: Maybe you can convert your question to find out how you can spawn these servers in parallel, to me i can suggest using `join_all` but the futures you are generating have different concrete types,so to do that you need to box them but you can look for a solution without boxing.

Comment: `join_all` like solution is a solution where you can propagate the error to the result of main, if you want to handle it on your own you can simply use another future which awaits for shutdown signal, you can use oneshot channel as like in this example : https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57357978/how-do-i-spawn-many-cancellable-timers-using-tokio/57359284#57359284

Comment: @ÖmerErden Yeah, I initially implemented this with `join_all`, but it was not running things concurrently. I think the point is that I need to run `join_all` what is returned from `spawn`?

Comment: Well that would have been a better and concise solution,

Comment: @ÖmerErden aside from one operating on an iterable vs a hand written list of objects, is there a difference in operation between `join_all` and  the `join!` macro?

Comment: I am not sure about efficiency but behavioral, both do the same thing.